# When does @JsonProperty rename object field?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

```
@Data
public class Tests {
    @JsonProperty("comment")
    private String notes;
}
```

I know how to use @JsonProperty to rename field as another name, but when does it rename the object field? For example, `notes` is renamed to `comment`. 
I try to read the source code and find that there is some relative code in `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase#serializeFields` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter#serializeAsField`. But the field has already been renamed as `comment`. So where does `@JsonProperty` rename object field?

Comment: So far I know there is an `Object Mapper` by default which serializes and deserializes a JSON object then when the `Tests` object is used to be serialized/deserialized at that time the mapper maps the JSON property name to the annotated Java field's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property name resolving happens in `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`
Have a look at this fragment:

```
public PropertyName findNameForDeserialization(Annotated a) {
    ...
    // Get JsonProperty value for the field
    JsonProperty pann = (JsonProperty)this._findAnnotation(a, JsonProperty.class);
    if (pann != null) {
        // here we are !!!
        return PropertyName.construct(pann.value());
    } else {
        return !useDefault && !this._hasOneOf(a, ANNOTATIONS_TO_INFER_DESER) ? null : PropertyName.USE_DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

All it happens in `POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll()`

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple Pojo class

```
public class JsonTest {
  @JsonProperty("greetings")
  String hello;
}
```

and run ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString method. After debugging for a while, I found that Jackson renames property name in the following method.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector#_renameProperties
```